# Filter list of dictionaries by key value - return answers as a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to filter.

```
[{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 3},
 {"Slope": -0.362, "Count": 6},
 {"Slope": -0.762, "Count": 8},
 {"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 12},
 {"Slope": 2.5, "Count": 34},
 {"Slope": 1.52, "Count": 2},
 {"Slope": .56, "Count": 6}]
```

My goal is to get a list of two dictionaries. One with the "highest count and a POSITVE slope" and the other with the "highest count and NEGATIVE slope".

My plan was to filter all the positive and negative ones out, then sort each list and then create a new list with the first record of each.

Sorting the list isnt an issue for me, i've got this!

```
lines_lst.sort(key=lambda i: i['lines_count'])
```

But filtering doesn't seem to work when I try this as it returns a dictionary.

```
positive_lines = next(item for item in lines_lst if item["Slope"] > 0)
```

Does anyone have a solution that ends up with the below?

```
[{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 12},{"Slope": 2.5, "Count": 34}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want max and min .. use them and apply a suitable key function - in fact using tuples you only need max:

```
data = [{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 3},
        {"Slope": -0.362, "Count": 6},
        {"Slope": -0.762, "Count": 8},
        {"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 12},
        {"Slope": 2.5, "Count": 34},
        {"Slope": 1.52, "Count": 2},
        {"Slope": .56, "Count": 6}]

m1 = max(data, key= lambda x: (x["Slope"]>0, x["Count"]))
m2 = max(data, key= lambda x: (x["Slope"]<0, x["Count"]))

result = [m1,m2]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}, {'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}]
```

Tuples sort by 1st value, then second value - you can build tuples and use them as max key function.

Comment: @bradSolomon that would take even less computation - agreed - but sorting would put those with negative slope and fewest counts and the back - not quite what is needed?

Comment: It works amazing!! BUT....It turns out that I might not always have a pair of positive and negative points. Do you know how I can just order each each positive and negative slope value into a list into an ordered list (by "count")? Then I can check then length of both and add some extra conditions after that?

Comment: @Lew you probably want to go with BradSolomons or Vasilis approach:  list comprehension: `a,b = sorted( (i for i in data if i["Slope"] < 0), key = lambda x:x["Count"]), sorted( (i for i in data if i["Slope"] >= 0), key = lambda x:x["Count"])`  or use the `filter( )` function to do the same. You should include "Slope" == 0 in one of both cases though, else you will eliminate these values.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to `max()`:

```
>>> max((d for d in lines_lst if d["Slope"] > 0), key=lambda d: d["Count"])
{'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}
>>> max((d for d in lines_lst if d["Slope"] < 0), key=lambda d: d["Count"])
{'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}
```

Granted, this solution iterates through `lines_lst` twice. If you have a really large input, you could iterate through it once, greedily, keeping track of the running max/min:

```
import sys

max_pos, max_neg = {"Count": -sys.maxsize}, {"Count": -sys.maxsize}
for d in lines_lst:
    ct = d["Count"]
    if d["Slope"] > 0 and ct > max_pos["Count"]:
        max_pos = d
    elif d["Slope"] < 0 and ct > max_neg["Count"]:
        max_neg = d
```

But in Python-land, this is probably only valuable if your input is really large and unwieldy.

Note that in both these cases, _further modifications to `max_pos`/`max_neg` constitute modifications to the members of `lines_lst`, because those members are mutable dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
inList = [{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 3},
{"Slope": -0.362, "Count": 6},
{"Slope": -0.762, "Count": 8},
{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 12},
{"Slope": 2.5, "Count": 34},
{"Slope": 1.52, "Count": 2},
{"Slope": .56, "Count": 6}]

maximum = max(filter(lambda elem: elem['Slope'] > 0, inList), key=lambda e: e['Count'])
minimum = max(filter(lambda elem: elem['Slope'] < 0, inList), key=lambda e: e['Count'])
```

This will return:

```
{'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}
{'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Count2 key that is negative for negative slopes. Then sort by Count2 and take the first and last elements.

```
lines_lst = [{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 3},
 {"Slope": -0.362, "Count": 6},
 {"Slope": -0.762, "Count": 8},
 {"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 12},
 {"Slope": 2.5, "Count": 34},
 {"Slope": 1.52, "Count": 2},
 {"Slope": .56, "Count": 6}]


for i in range(len(lines_lst)):
    lines_lst[i]['Count2'] = lines_lst[i]['Count']*lines_list[i]['Slope']/abs(lines_list[i]['Slope'])

lines_lst.sort(key=lambda i: i['Count2'])

[lines_lst[0], lines_lst[-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your additional info in Patrick's answer, you can do this to get the negative/positive lists sorted first:

```
positives = sorted((v for v in data if v['Slope'] >= 0), key=lambda x: x['Count'])
negatives = sorted((v for v in data if v['Slope'] < 0), key=lambda x: x['Count'])

# positives:
# [{'Slope': 1.52, 'Count': 2}, {'Slope': 0.56, 'Count': 6}, {'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}]

# negatives:
# [{'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 3}, {'Slope': -0.362, 'Count': 6}, {'Slope': -0.762, 'Count': 8}, {'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}]
```

Getting the max at this point is simple.  Just retrieve the last element:

```
max_pox = positives[-1]     # {'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}
max_neg = negatives[-1]     # {'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}
```

Or if you prefer in a list form:

```
[x[-1] for x in (negatives, positives)]

# [{'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}, {'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
data = [{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 3},
{"Slope": -0.362, "Count": 6},
{"Slope": -0.762, "Count": 8},
{"Slope": -0.562, "Count": 12},
{"Slope": 2.5, "Count": 34},
{"Slope": 1.52, "Count": 2},
{"Slope": .56, "Count": 6}]
positive_lines = []
negative_lines = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i]["Slope"] < 0:
        negative_lines.append(data[i])
    else:
        positive_lines.append(data[i])
max_counts = []
max_counts.append(max(positive_lines, key=lambda x:x['Count']))
max_counts.append(max(negative_lines, key=lambda x:x['Count']))
print(max_counts)
```

Output:

```
[{'Slope': 2.5, 'Count': 34}, {'Slope': -0.562, 'Count': 12}]
```